# silverlight 3 how can i get element under mouse

Tags: silverlight-3.0

How can i get element under mouse. I try to get this under mouse move event.
Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838402(v=VS.95).aspx) method.

[Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2009/08/11/silverlight-quick-tip-how-to-perform-a-hit-test.aspx) is an example.